# Basic question about notation in group theory

Tags: group-theory, notation

Am I correct in thinking that it, for the group $(G,*)$ with $x \in G$ we have $x^{n}=x*x*...*x$ (n copies of $x$), with the only exception being additive groups, where $x^{n}$ does not make sense and should be written as $nx$?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.

Just note that the precise definition of $x^n$ is an inductive one:

$x^0=e$

$x^{n} = x * x^{n-1}$ for $n\ge1$

$x^{-n} = (x^{n})^{-1}$